# Message from Windows "example.com is not responding". Is it about the app, IT infrastructure or the browser?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 intranet application.
Our URLs are only visible for the employees of the company.
Our domain is called telecare.dk

When employees are using the app, they sometimes get the message
"telecare.dk is not responding - Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..."
(see screenshot) - We are using IE. It's only sometimes, now and then, that they are experiencing this problem.
http://1drv.ms/1kreLV2

**My question is: 
Is this message something to do with the app?
Or is it something to do with the IT infrastructure?
Say the strength of the internet connection?
Or is it an issue with the IE browser?**

Comment: What's hard to understand in @TomTom's answer ? It could be any and all of the above or something entirely different. Honestly, you and the infrastructure team need to get together and start diagnosing the problem. You need to instrument your app, monitor the network, watch packets going too and fro and make a decision based on what you find.

Comment: I would as I said start assuming it is the server. Unless you are in a SMALL company, the infrastructure guys will NOT take you serious unless you have done a server check. "It works for everyone else" is what you will hear. So regardless what it is - you should precheck this part so you have arguments.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's appreciated. I plan to leave the question open for a little while, to see what suggestions are coming in. I have no knowledge about IT infrastructure, but your answers give me something which I can send to the infrastructure guy in the company.

Comment: Currently it's only an occasional problem on 1 out of 3 locations, if we at sometime discover the precise origin of the problem I will come back here and tell you. But our discussion here has been useful for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be multiple things, but it is very likely that this is related to some infrastructure element.

THAT SAID: Start checking servers (logs) - the Infrastructure guys will not accept the blame without some arguments.

But unless the server is seriously overloaded and / or has serious issues (seen servers loosing network connectivity regularly due to faulty network ports on router and / or network card side) this points to either a DNS or a routing / bandwidth issue.

Comment: Thank you, actually I also think Farhan Khan answer (below) adds to the picture of possible causes for the problem, but apparently this site does not allow marking multiple answers as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a scripting issue. See if any of these fixes the issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260.

What version of IE are you using? Press `F12` and click on `console` to see if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: They are using the latest IE. We have used same the app on 3 different psysical locations in 2 countries, but only one location has reported this occasional problem. Yes there could be an issue with the JavaScript and IE 11. Thank you :)

Comment: @RuneHansen This is important information and a good argument for the infrastructure discussion - OBVIOUSLY it can not be a server problem if multiple sites have no problem at the same time a specific site experiences issues. It could be configuration, but that makes a defective network card a very unlikely argument, for example.